# Direction of the torque

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, torque

> In each one of the following figures there's a pole of length $1.2
>  \text{m}$ and there's a force $\vec F = 150 \text{N}$ acting on it.
>   Determine the torque that is created by the force relative to the axis
>   of rotation $O$.

[image: Illustration]

I had no problem with calculating the magnitude of the torque, but I did have a problem determining its direction in fig. $D$. I used the rule of the right hand and I got that its direction is "outside the monitor" while according to the answers it has the same direction as in all the other figures before (i.e. "inside the monitor"). I'm also wondering whether the vectors directions are important in cross product. For example - is the direction of the displacement vector is important? If it is, then how can I apply the rule of the right hand here when the thumb and the index finger aren't starting from the same position.

Comment: Vectors encode magnitude and position *only*. Where you choose to draw them is just that - a choice to help remind yourself where the relevant interaction is. You can always slide all vectors to originate at the origin if it helps visualize the cross product.

Comment: @ChrisWhite - I understand that. But what about that particular example at fig. $D$ - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Umm, the direction of $\vec{\tau}$ *is* into the plane for D (the rod will clearly rotate clockwise), while it is out of the plane for A, B, and C (it will rotate counterclockwise). Is this not what the answers say?

Comment: @ChrisWhite - that's what I thought as well, but no, the book says it is the same in all these cases (except of course from the last ones where the torque is simply zero). Because I'm new to that, I was thinking that I got the whole cross product thing wrong. It seems like the book has a mistake. Thank you for confirming that assumption!

Comment: Al long as $\tau$ has *positive* magnitude, the directions will be different. The book *might* be doing something confusing and saying the directions are all the same but the magnitudes change sign. (I don't know *why* they would obfuscate things this way, but there it is.)

Comment: @ChrisWhite - actually they say in the question "...find the torque (magnitude and the algebraic sign)...". But in the answers all the magnitudes they give are positive - maybe they decided not to mention the signs themselves in the answers (which is less expected as they do mention in other questions) or it is indeed some mistake (that happens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The torque is defined as the cross product between the force vector and the displacement vector from the center of the object to the point where the force is applied: $\vec{\tau}=\vec{r}\times\vec{F}$.

The direction of the vectors is important when calculating cross products. Notice if the direction is reversed in the displacement vector:

$$\vec{r}\times\vec{F}=(r_yF_z-r_zF_y)\hat{i}+(r_zF_x-r_xF_z)\hat{j}+(r_xF_y-r_yF_x)\hat{k}$$

$$-\vec{r}\times\vec{F}=(-r_yF_z+r_zF_y)\hat{i}+(-r_zF_x+r_xF_z)\hat{j}+(-r_xF_y+r_yF_x)\hat{k}$$

$$-\vec{r}\times\vec{F}=-(\vec{r}\times\vec{F})$$

So as you can see, reversing the direction of the displacement vector will reverse the direction of the torque. A similar proof will demonstrate that the same will happen if the force vector is reversed.

Another way to look at the right hand rule (because I too have a bit of trouble using the finger rules) is to instead think of it as, put the bases of the two vectors together, curl your fingers in a direction that goes from the first vector ($\vec{r}$ in this case) to the second vector ($\vec{F}$). The direction that your thumb points in is the direction of the torque.

Comment: The reasoning is correct but the definition is not: it's the other way around and as the cross product is antisymetric, it will change the sign: $\vec{\tau}=\vec{r}\times\vec{F} = - \vec{F}\times\vec{r}$

Comment: I appreciate your answer regarding the cross product, but could you elaborate more on that particular example I gave? I can't actually put together the bases of the vectors (for example in the 1st figure) because then the displacement vector will change and there will be no torque. As I understand, what I can do is to move the vector in its direction (which helps) - in the first example I can move $\vec F$ only vertically. But still, I can do the right hand trick only if I assume that the base of the displacement vector is not in $O$ but in the point where the force is applied.

Comment: @brmch8 You can slide $\vec{F}$ to the origin, but the displacement $\vec{r}$ does not change. $\vec{r}$ is *not* the vector from the origin to the location where you choose to draw $\vec{F}$, it is the vector pointing along the rod whose magnitude is the distance between the origin and the point of the applied force.

Comment: @ChrisWhite - how it doesn't change? Suppose I move $\vec F$ to $O$. That way there would be no torque, am I wrong? Maybe the correct way to ask it - what do you mean by "origin"?

Comment: @brmch8 Yes, you can move either of the vectors as much as you want without changing their value. Translating a vector doesn't change its value, only rotating or scaling it does. Translating the vector to O (the origin) does not mean that you're now applying the force at the origin, a vector only consists of a direction and a magnitude.

Comment: @ZettaSuro - I do know that if I don't change the magnitude and the direction of the vector it is okay. But we have here a free body diagram - if I move $\vec F$ horizontally, just displacing it, without changing nor its direction nor its value I change the displacement vector's magnitude which is defined as a vector from the point of the axis of rotation ($O$ in this case) to the point where the force is applied. To paraphrase - by moving the $\vec F$ vector I just apply the force in a different point - the torque is all about this thing.

Comment: No, moving the vector doesn't mean that you're literally moving where the force is applied. There is a difference between moving the vectors and moving the actual point of torque action. Just move $\vec{F}$ to the axis of rotation and **don't** change the displacement vector.

Moving $\vec{F}$ is not applying the force at a different point. This is a fundamental concept you'll need to understand in order to grasp the mathematics of rotational dynamics.

Comment: @brmch8 Moving a vector is like moving the compass on a map - you are not declaring that the north pole has moved, or that the center of the Earth is in a new location. Boston will always be north of New York, no matter where the compass is, and the point of contact will always be $\vec{r}$ away from the origin, no matter where $\vec{F}$ is drawn.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my stupiditiy. I was thinking of this as a physical process rather than mathematical. So basically, in the first example using the rule of the thumb and by moving $\vec F$ to $O$ I'd get that the cross product is going "inside the monitor" (sorry, I don't know how to name this direction correctly) right?

Comment: @brmch8 Yes exactly. And "inside the monitor" is fine ;)

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much gentlemen! I appreciate your efforts and your time for me!